# How to search for groups or users in the Box API

Tags: box-api

How can I get a user or group id from box other than iterating through all users or groups in an enterprise.

I can search for folders by name:
https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query="Colab Folder 3"&scope=enterprise_content&type=folder

but not for groups, or users:

/api.box.com/2.0/search?query="Colab Group 3"&scope=enterprise_content&type=group

/api.box.com/2.0/search?query="foo42@bar.com"&scope=enterprise_content&type=user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (and only if) you are an enterprise admin, you can do at least some of what you're asking.

**Users**

You can [search for a specific user](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise) via the `/users` endpoint with a `filter_term`:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users?filter_term=foo42%40bar.com
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

**Groups**

All of the `/groups` endpoints appear to be scoped to a single user, so I'm not sure there is an API method to find a group by name. However, if you know of a user that's in the group, you can use the method above to find that user and then [fetch all of their groups](http://developers.box.com/docs/#groups-get-all-group-memberships-for-a-user):

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/USER_ID/memberships
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

This should net you a pretty small list that can be filtered client-side.

Comment: curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/USER_ID/memberships did not work for me, but:

curl https://api.box.com/2.0/groups
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
-H "As_User: USER_ID"

did.

Thanks for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: I take it back. api.box.com/2.0/users/USER_ID/memberships worked fine in curl it failed in POSTMAN.